# Excel stops responding when comparing two worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have to compare data between two worksheets and find the rows that have similar values. I have multiple values in a single row and these values match values from another row in a different sheet. I would like these values to be highlighted.

I have code which works on small data, for example 10 rows from each sheet.

On more data, Excel stops responding. I found the overhead between the VBA and Excel is causing the unresponsive behavior.

```
Sub CompareRanges()
'Update 20130815
Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", xTitleId, "", Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Range B:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    rng1Value = Rng1.Value
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If rng1Value = Rng2.Value Then
            Rng1.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding **DoEvents** in your loops should solve "excel not responding" issue.

```
Sub CompareRanges()
'Update 20130815
Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", xTitleId, "", Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Range B:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    DoEvents
    rng1Value = Rng1.Value
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        DoEvents
        If rng1Value = Rng2.Value Then
            Rng1.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Rng2.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```